# Segmentation error in C

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, segmentation-fault

EDIT: the default for the switch is "invalid option", and i am just trying to create a tree that's all, the program is getting compiled and when i select the option for creating a tree it simply says segmentation error

I've been doing simple data structures programs for the past few days, and the segmentation error is the one bothering me a lot, i researched on the internet about the error and got this  [link](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html) and actually it didn't help.

I'm trying to create a binary search tree. and the return type for create is not void, it struct tree *

program:

```
struct tree{
      int data;
      struct tree *rchild, *lchild;
    };



struct tree * create(struct tree * root, int d){
  if(root==NULL) {
      root = (struct tree *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
      root->data=d;
      root->rchild=NULL;
      root->lchild=NULL;
  }else  if(root->data < d)     create(root->rchild, d);

  else if(root->data > d)     create(root->lchild, d);

  else if(root->data == d)  printf("duplication error");

}  
main(){
  struct tree *root;
  int choice, c;

  while(choice!=5){
  printf("Enter choice\n1-insert into  tree\n5-exit");
  scanf("%d", &choice);

  switch(choice){
     case 1: 
     printf("enter data to be inserted");
     scanf("%d",&c);          
     printf("error after scanf  ");
     create(root,c); 
     break; 
     case 5: exit(0); default: printf("invalid option");
  }
  }
}
```

and the OS i'm using is Backtrack 5 R1

to the one who gave -1: Sir, please tell the answer to my question if it's so silly and non constructive

there is a similar [linked list question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821013/segmentation-fault-error-in-c), I've also answered that question, and I'm writing a tree program by the way.

Comment: actually you can run this c program, and when i ran it in gcc it is compiling and when i execute it is just displays Segmentation Fault, and absolutely no more information

Comment: What kind of input should I give?

Comment: the stage of input doesn't come! after compilation when you'll try to execute it it'll show segmentation error!

Comment: @lucifer That should not happen. Your algorithm is incorrect (as gnawux explains below), but the program should start and show the program without error. Which compiler/compiler options are you using?

Comment: So I built this and it says `error after scanf` for inputs `1`,`23`

Comment: Also, why *are* you using Backtrack Linux? I can't quite see why this would be the problem, but - use the right tools for the right job. Backtrack has a very specialized application domain, just because someone said that it was "1337 h4xx0r styl3" doesn't mean it should be your main OS.

Comment: You should pay attention to (and fix) the compiler warnings for issues such as your search functions declared to return a value and not doing so.  Most likely, you should modify the functions so they don't return anything (`void`).  Otherwise, you need to consistently return something.  If your compiler isn't griping, get a better compiler.  This isn't the cause of your crash, but it is indicative a bad habit (ignoring what your compiler tells you is wrong) that you should break now.  (Compile with `gcc -Wall` and make the compilation silent.)

Comment: @us2012 I use BT for network analysis and testing

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually i am trying to insert nodes, the search functions are not used by me i just wrote them, and pertaining to the traversal functions they've got to return something as i'm using recursion to traverse... How can they not return anything and the program can still run??/

Comment: Then why are you making us look at the search code?  You need to learn about creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  One major part of that is removing the extraneous.  —— Now fixed; thank you!

Comment: You should have something like: `if (scanf("%d", &c) != 1) printf("Error\n"); else create(root, c);` with your current code.  Your problem has been correctly diagnosed by [gnawux](http://stackoverflow.com/users/785483/gnawux) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14866549/15168).

Comment: Please take the habit to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, I do not think the create() can work correctly.

You should use struct tree ** instead of struct tree *.

As your node root is NULL, create(root) means create(NULL), which can not assign the allocated memory to root. You should define it as create(struct tree**), and call it with create(&root)

Comment: +1: Of itself, `create()` allocates OK; it just has no way to tell the calling function what it allocated — as you state.  The function could return the (new) `root` value, or it could take a double-pointer as you suggest.

Comment: @gnawux actually yes, the create function is giving an error, and i can't put my finger on it,

Answer (score 0):

You are malloc'ing `root` in the create function, but there is no reason why that survives the call, since it is not being passed by reference. If you passed &root, you could then change *root. As it is, you do not create new nodes in your tree... every time you return from `create`, the `root` pointer is NULL...

Alternatively, you could return the new value of `root` as the return value of the call, and call it with

```
root = create( root, c);
```

You can prove this to yourself by adding

```
printf("root is now %p\n", root);
```

after your `create` call...

In short, the following works:

```
struct tree{
      int data;
      struct tree *rchild, *lchild;
    };

struct tree* create(struct tree * root, int d){
  printf("creating node with d = %d\n", d);
  if(root==NULL) {
      root = (struct tree *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
      root->data=d;
      root->rchild=NULL;
      root->lchild=NULL;
  }else  if(root->data < d)     create(root->rchild, d);

  else if(root->data > d)     create(root->lchild, d);

  else if(root->data == d)  printf("duplication error");
 return root;
}
main(){
  struct tree *root;
  int choice, c;

  while(choice!=5){
  printf("Enter choice\n1-insert into  tree\n5-exit");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
  printf("root is now %p\n", root);
  switch(choice){
     case 1:
     printf("enter data to be inserted");
     scanf("%d",&c);
     printf("made it past scanf\n");
     root = create(root,c);
     break;
     case 5: exit(0);
     default: printf("invalid option\n");
 }
  }
}
```